# VueJS detecting if a button was clicked in Watch method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am creating undo/redo functionality in VueJS. I `watch` the settings and add a new element to an array of changes when the settings change. I also have a method for undo when the undo button is clicked.

However, when the button is clicked and the last setting is reverted, the settings are changed and the watch is fired again.

How can I prevent a new element being added to the array of changes if the settings changed but it was because the Undo button was clicked?

```
(function () {

var Admin = {};
Admin.init = function () {

};

var appData = {
    settings: {
        has_border: true,
        leave_reviews: true,
        has_questions: true
    },
    mutations: [],
    mutationIndex: null,
    undoDisabled: true,
    redoDisabled: true
};

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: appData,
    methods: {
        undo: function() {
            if (this.mutations[this.mutationIndex - 1]) {
                let settings = JSON.parse(this.mutations[this.mutationIndex - 1]);
            
                this.settings = settings;
                this.mutationIndex = this.mutations.length - 1;
                
                console.log (settings);
            }
        },
        redo: function() {
            
        }
    },
    computed: {
        border_class: {
            get: function () {
                return this.settings.has_border ? ' rp-pwb' : ''
            }
        },
        undo_class: {
            get: function () {
                return this.undoDisabled ? ' disabled' : ''
            }
        },
        redo_class: {
            get: function () {
                return this.redoDisabled ? ' disabled' : ''
            }
        }
    },
    watch: {
        undoDisabled: function () {
            return this.mutations.length;
        },
        redoDisabled: function () {
            return this.mutations.length;
        },
        settings: {
            handler: function () {

                let mutation = JSON.stringify(this.settings),
                    prevMutation = JSON.stringify(this.mutations[this.mutations.length-1]);

                if (mutation !== prevMutation) {
                    this.mutations.push(mutation);
                    this.mutationIndex = this.mutations.length - 1;
                    this.undoDisabled = false;
                }
            },
            deep: true
        }
    }
});

Admin.init();
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you make the changes with a button click, you can create a method to achieve your goal instead of using watchers.

```
methods: {
   settings() {
      // call this method from undo and redo methods if the conditions are met.
      // move the watcher code here.
   }
}
```

BTW,
If you don't use setter in computed properties, you don't need getters, so that is enough:

```
border_class() {
    return this.settings.has_border ? ' rp-pwb' : ''
},
```

These watchers codes look belong to computed:

```
undoDisabled() {
    return this.mutations.length;
},
redoDisabled() {
    return this.mutations.length;
},
```

Comment: If I move settings to methods, I get the error `vue.js:634 [Vue warn]: Method "settings" has already been defined as a data property.`

Comment: The settings object has some default properties and when these settings are changed it should create the new mutation in the array

Comment: Change the method name, and arrange your code accordingly.

Comment: But then what will bind the settings object to the method?

Comment: There is no such thing as binding object to method. Just change the object values in your method if it's necessary.